# Loop inside Pentaho Data Integration Transformation

Tags: loops, text-files, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have a  transformation as

[image]

where the text file is in the following format:

[image]

For each of the t_cmp(the number of t_cmp is not known prior) in the text file, I want to execute Read Company

[image]

But it is giving error as

[image]

Can anyone please tell me where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass 3 rows, each with 1 field, instead of a single row with 3 fields.

The number of fields must match the number of parameters of your query.

So, in short, transpose your data. Either:

- read line as a single field then use Split field to rows
- or read as now and use Row normalizer

Both approaches should work.